# How to make proper toggle button for radio input?

Tags: javascript, html, css, sass, frontend

I`m trying to make a toggle button in CSS to change the theme for a calculator page, but the selector only works on the third theme and moving to start when I select the second radio.

```css
.form-choice {

        #first:checked + .slider:before {
          transform: translateX(0px);
          background-color: red;
        }

        #second:checked + .slider:before {
          transform: translateX(15px);
          background-color: black;
        }

        #third:checked + .slider:before {
          transform: translateX(45px);
          background-color: yellow;
        }
      }
```

```html
<div class="theme-selector">
          <div id="theme-name">Theme</div>
          <div class="theme-form">
            <div class="form-name">
              <label for="first">1</label>
              <label for="second">2</label>
              <label for="third">3</label>
            </div>
            <div class="form-choice">
              <input type="radio" id="first" name="choice" />
              <input type="radio" id="second" name="choice" />
              <input type="radio" id="third" name="choice" />
              <span class="slider"></span>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
```

I want the slider to move according to selected the theme.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You’re using the wrong selector in your CSS.
The `+` selector is called an “adjacent sibling” selector. It will select only the second element so long as it immediately follows the first.

The `~` is a “general sibling” selector and doesn’t have the same condition of having to immediately follow the first element.

Try:

```
#first:checked ~ .slider:before {
   transform: translateX(0px);
   background-color: red;
}

#second:checked ~ .slider:before {
   transform: translateX(15px);
   background-color: black;
}

#third:checked ~ .slider:before {
   transform: translateX(45px);
   background-color: yellow;
}
```